# Router configuration

Tags: wireless-networking, router, tomcat

I have a Netgear WNR1000 router. On my PC I am running a tomcat server on port 8001. But the problem is I cannot browse the tomcat server from my phone (though both phone and pc are under same LAN) neither from my other computer. However I can ping and reach each other. I am sure that the tomcat server is running, because I can browse the server on same pc (by same pc i mean where tomcat is running).

Also, how can I configure so that all other devices under LAN can reach each other?

Comment: Did you check your PC's firewall configuration?